# How to use a global variable in HTML and use it in typescript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to define a variable in my index.html file and use it in my angular4/typescript code and I get a compile error.

my compile error is:

```
Error:(109, 27) TS2339: Property 'standalone' does not exist on type 'Window'.
```

the variable definition in HTML is:
    
        var standalone = 'true';

```
    System.import('app').catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
</script>
```

the typescript code is:

```
if(window.standalone !== undefined) {
    console.log('standalone');
}
```

Anyone sees what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I do something similar in one of my projects and I found you can’t simply access the window object like that. Check this out for a simple(ish) alternative: https://juristr.com/blog/2016/09/ng2-get-window-ref/#register-windowref-as-provider

Comment: I am surprised that this is this involved. One would think this is not an uncommon thing to want to do. But thanks

Comment: `if((window as any).standalone !== undefined) {
    console.log('standalone');
}`

Comment: thank you that last comment is correct and it works. How do I give you credit for your response?

Answer (score 3):

Global variables should be declared as globals in TypeScript:

```
declare var standalone: boolean;
```

In order to be referenced `window` property, a global should be also specified as such:

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    standalone: boolean;
  }
}
```

If global variable is used one or several times and cannot benefit from type checks, types can be intentionally skipped instead:

```
if((<any>window).standalone !== undefined) ...
```

Or:

```
if(window['standalone'] !== undefined) ...
```